# Apache2 with mod_deflate serve bad css and js

Tags: apache-http-server, ubuntu-14.04, gzip

Problem I am having is with css and js files **served as file.css.gz and file.js.gz** on one of enabled sites.
The content is served as this gibberish:

```
û—Û6’0ú»ÿ
­sæÚNZ²H½ZÎ‰¿yìN&9Iv¿yå5sï¡H¨Å˜5$Õïõ÷·_$ˆÂ£Šº“Ý¹gí™¸›¨*P P(^<ú÷#;Œþ”êÑ¯·å¡o“”ÞåÍèã×Ï^<úí¿}þÅ7£¯ò›ü`þóÙhÔý¶Ï‹‡7£=©Ÿò²ºJßŒNUñòÅkV¿–D^ 3–¿NXÙ¼xuøÿú(gÛüþÅ+^{µOš—/Ø~Ã²Œeã’7GöâÕÕ0©»r»DÚ_ðš¢5Õ‰WYßÞ|¤>É/€/k;BöéÅoF³é´ÿV7{3:„âÓg„xþí›ÕÂéÅõGvs*’ê±ëÈèVt¡Q(% <7L€(:b÷mPŒJf’rëeùE“yúXQ¶TtcÚß Aâˆ! D3L„2`ûéBùåÈOËªßoË"{¬ð
Ý
```

In .htaccess file in css and js folder for them I've got the following:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Make sure the browser supports gzip encoding before we send it
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} \b(x-)?gzip\b
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -s
RewriteRule ^(.+) $1.gz [L]

# without it, Content-Type will be "application/x-gzip"
# also add a content-encoding header to tell the browser to decompress

<FilesMatch \.css\.gz$>
    ForceType text/css
    Header set Content-Encoding gzip
    Header add Vary Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
```

I am running on Ubuntu 14.04 apache2 2.4.7 with mod_deflate installed when I run `apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES` it shows `deflate_module (shared)` and `headers_module (shared)`

What could be the problem?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @heavyd I edited my question I think the correct term is serving pre-compressed files

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by adding following lines in my vhost conf file:

```
<Directory /home/nexusstar/workspace/{{path to js folder}}/js>
    AddEncoding gzip gz
    ForceType text/javascript
</Directory>
<Directory /home/nexusstar/workspace/{{path to css folder}}/css>
    AddEncoding gzip gz
    ForceType text/css
</Directory>
```